# Nested Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

can we use two gridview in a single xml file.it display onle first gridview.. how can i use two gridview together.i want to display pics from drawable folder in first gridview & from url in second gridview. pls guide me..

this is gridview.xml--

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
  </GridView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

this is imageadapter class which display pic in gridview.

```
   public class image extends BaseAdapter {
private Context c;
int h = 0;
public Integer[] pic = { R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3,
        R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5, R.drawable.i6 };

public final static String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[] {
              "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s160-c/A%252520Photographer.jpg","https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s160-c/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s160-c/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",       "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s160-c/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg","https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s160-c/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-s-AFpvgSeew/URquc6dF-JI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Mt3xNGRUd68/s160-c/Backlit%252520Cloud.jpg",       "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bvmif9a9YOQ/URquea3heHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/rcr6wyeQtAo/s160-c/Bee%252520and%252520Flower.jpg","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n7mdm7I7FGs/URqueT_BT-I/AAAAAAAAAbs/9MYmXlmpSAo/s160-c/Bonzai%252520Rock%252520Sunset.jpg","https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4CN4X4t0M1k/URqufPozWzI/AAAAAAAAAbs/8wK41lg1KPs/s160-c/Caterpillar.jpg","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-rrFnVC8xQEg/URqufdrLBaI/AAAAAAAAAbs/s69WYy_fl1E/s160-c/Chess.jpg","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WVpRptWH8Yw/URqugh-QmDI/AAAAAAAAAbs/E-MgBgtlUWU/s160-c/Chihuly.jpg","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0BDXkYmckbo/URquhKFW84I/AAAAAAAAAbs/ogQtHCTk2JQ/s160-c/Closed%252520Door.jpg","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PyggXXZRykM/URquh-kVvoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hFtDwhtrHHQ/s160-c/Colorado%252520River%252520Sunset.jpg","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZAs4dNZtALc/URquikvOCWI/AAAAAAAAAbs/DXz4h3dll1Y/s160-c/Colors%252520of%252520Autumn.jpg",           "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GztnWEIiMz8/URqukVCU7bI/AAAAAAAAAbs/jo2Hjv6MZ6M/s160-c/Countryside.jpg","https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bEg9EZ9QoiM/URquklz3FGI/AAAAAAAAAbs/UUuv8Ac2BaE/s160-c/Death%252520Valley%252520-%252520Dunes.jpg","https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ijQJ8W68tEE/URqulGkvFEI/AAAAAAAAAbs/zPXvIwi_rFw/s160-c/Delicate%252520Arch.jpg",         "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Oh8mMy2ieng/URqullDwehI/AAAAAAAAAbs/TbdeEfsaIZY/s160-c/Despair.jpg",    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gl0y4UiAOlk/URqumC_KjBI/AAAAAAAAAbs/PM1eT7dn4oo/s160-c/Eagle%252520Fall%252520Sunrise.jpg"};

public image(Context c1) {
    Log.i("iamgeclass", "create");
    c = c1;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pic.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pic[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView i;
    i = new ImageView(c);
    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    i.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    i.setImageResource(pic[pos]);

         ImageLoader ps = new ImageLoader(c);
     ps.DisplayImage(imageThumbUrls[pos], i);

    return i;

}
}
```

this is imageloader class which use to display pic from url.
    public class ImageLoader {

```
MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new  WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
 ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
  }

  int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  public void DisplayImage(String url,ImageView imageView)
  {
    //stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
      //  imageView.setImageResource(loader);
    }
  }

  private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
  {
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
   }

  private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
  {
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
  }

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
 private class PhotoToLoad
 {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
 }

  class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
  }

  boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
   }

  //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
  class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
   {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

can anyone tell me where is the mistake..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I can only see a single GridView in your layout, if you want it side by side do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then just set two different adapters or two instances of the same adapter to each GridView. Please further explain your problem if i missed anything.

I assigned the adapters like this: (You need two different adapters or check the id of each gridview inside the adapter)

```
gridview2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview2);
gridview2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Comment: not working.. display only those pics which refer to first gridview.. and ofcourse thats right because first gridview cover the entire screen.. so how to display second gridview in same activity.. any idea??

Comment: the gridview will expand to fill whatever it needs (as its parent has fill_parent attribute, embed each gridview in a different linear layour and set 0.5 weight to each one.

Comment: just tried it in a gridview project i had around, just pasted my code so please modify it to suit your needs. (modified it in the answer)

Comment: :heyy!! it's working :) thank u so much...but it display both side by side..i want to display drawable images in upper side of screen and from url in below that.. pls suggest me.

Comment: just change first layout orientation xD (and please check this as answered)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible.

You could try any of the below approach:

- Use a Single GridView. Load the image URI from drawable folder and also the images from URL into an arraylist and setup the adapter and hence the GridView.
- If you need two gridViews in a Single Activity, Create Two fragments with gridView in each layout. Load the drawable images in one gridView of "fragment A" and Url images in "fragment B". And In the FragmentActivity's layout, just include both fragments.

Comment: @Santosh:i tried ur fist suggestion but still it's not working..it display only pic from one locaion either from drawable or URL.